# R: Stack error - How to merge multiple columns into one very long column in R

Tags: r, stack

This should be easy but I'm having a lot of difficulty.

I have a relatively large dataset of medications, [image: looks like this:]

What I want is a table of frequencies, but ranging over ALL the columns - so I want the medication that appears the most commonly from columns 1:8.

My idea was to combine all of these columns into one long column, just one on top of the other. However, I have tried multiple function (stack, melt, matrix), but they all give me bizarre results. The one that seems correct for me to use is stack, but it keeps returning the error message "Error in stack.data.frame(meds) : no vector columns were selected". I've seen this error on the message boards before - I tried converting into as.vector, but this is not working. The object is definitely of class dataframe.

If there is another way to achieve these table results, that would be great, but either way, it's not working right now. Could somebody help?

Comment: You should just be able to use `stack(meds[,1:8])` it should return a two column dataframe, with the values and the column the value came from.

Comment: If that still gives you an error, try using `stack(as.data.frame(meds[,1:8], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))`

Comment: These are still giving me the same error - "no vector columns selected"

Answer (score 0):

Consider `do.call` or `Reduce` using `c()` function to combine all columns into a vector and then count unique meds using `sapply` loop:

```
set.seed(79)
meds <- data.frame(MED1=sample(LETTERS, 8),
                   MED2=sample(LETTERS, 8),
                   MED3=sample(LETTERS, 8),
                   MED4=sample(LETTERS, 8),
                   MED5=sample(LETTERS, 8),
                   MED6=sample(LETTERS, 8),
                   MED7=sample(LETTERS, 8),
                   MED8=sample(LETTERS, 8), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    

medslist <- do.call(c, meds)   # OR Reduce(c, meds)

medslength <- sapply(unique(medslist), function(i) length(medslist[medslist==i]))    
medslength <- sort(medslength, decreasing=TRUE)

medslength[1:8]
# B U W L I E M R 
# 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get what you want. No stacking necessary:

```
df = data.frame(Col1 = sample(LETTERS,50,replace=T),
                Col2 = sample(LETTERS,50,replace=T))

> table(as.matrix(df))

# A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
# 2 3 3 4 3 5 4 3 5 3 4 8 4 5 3 6 5 2 5 4 4 2 4 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks - this was a good and simple solution. One more thing - there are now a HUGE amount of medications in the array this saved out and I would like to see the top 20 or 30. I am able to export it to Excel and view it, but is there any way to view this array within R? Thanks!

Comment: Yes -- say your table is called `meds`; simply do `sort(meds, decreasing=T)[1:30]`

Comment: Ok. The issue is that I want these frequencies to be weighted (by a weighting variable I have pre-defined). When I try to use wtd.table with this algorithm (the as.matrix), many of the values become NA - not sure why. But ultimately, I need to be able to weight the frequencies.